# Grouping data into an average

Tags: r

I have the following df and wish to group all the data into an average on one line, like so;

current df

```
 1     2       3  4    5         6       7        8   9   10     11   12
1-33  FALSE    5 18 joe blogs    NA      NA       NA  NA  NA     NA   NA
2-33  FALSE    5 18 joe blogs    55      44       44  3   2     NA   NA
22-65 FALSE    5 18 joe blogs    65      40       71   5  1      29   NA
23-66 FALSE    5 18 joe blogs    NA      NA       NA  NA  NA     NA   NA
```

So my intended output here would be tp group all the data (columns 6-12) with an average based on columns 4 and 5 (which will both be the same), this will reduce the data into one line hopefully

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `dplyr` (>= 1.1.0 for reframe). Note that numbers as column names may cause problems down the line in other operations.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(`4`, `5`) %>% 
  reframe(across(`6`:`12`, ~ mean(.x[!is.na(.x)])))
# A tibble: 1 × 9
    `4` `5`         `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`
  <int> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    18 joe blogs    60    42  57.5     4   1.5    29   NaN
```